# Is there any way to convert from an iterator over owned objects to an iterator over references?

Tags: rust, iterator, ownership

I want to implement a function like this:

```rs
use proc_macro2::{TokenStream, TokenTree};

fn filter(tokens: &TokenStream, param: MyParams) -> impl Iterator<Item = &TokenTree> {
    tokens.into_iter().filter(...)
}
```

But I get the following error:

> type mismatch resolving `<std::iter::Filter<proc_macro2::token_stream::IntoIter, [closure@dgpu_compiler/src/utils/token_map.rs:15:38: 15:45]> as Iterator>::Item == &proc_macro2::TokenTree`

I guess this is because `TokenStream` implements `IntoIterator` with `Item = TokenTree`, not the reference.

Is there any way to get an iterator to references instead? I don't want to "consume" the TokenStream by giving away ownership of the items inside.

Comment: Have you simply tried `.iter()` instead of `.into_iter()`?

Comment: There is no` iter()` for `TokenStream`, AFAIK. And I'm actually surprised that this code didn't error out on `.into_iter()`, since it have to consume `TokenStream`.

Comment: Since it's proc macro and speed is not critical could you just clone `TokenStream` instead?

Comment: Cloning a `TokenStream` is cheap.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't really work if your aim is to mutate an existing token rather than create a new one.